# How to upgrade Bitcoin Core on Mac OS with binaries from tarball?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

I want to upgrade to version 0.21.1 from an older version I built from source. However, it is unclear to me how I can upgrade using the .tar.gz file that's available from the Bitcoin Core website.

I think I found how to do the first step:

```
tar -xvf bitcoin-0.21.1-osx64.tar.gz
```

But after that, it's unclear to me how to proceed. Just trying to learn this stuff - many thanks for your help.

Comment: why don’t you download the .dmg installer instead of the .tar?

Comment: Does that also update the binaries used for the CLI?

Comment: No, the binaries are in the tarball. Upgrading should be as simple as replacing the old ones with the new ones